# Enabled Brigded Network in Vmware Server

Tags: vmware, virtualization, vmware-server

I have the vmware server with this error, anyone knows how to fix it?[VMware Server Error http://soporte.cardinalsystems.com.ar/errorvmwareserver.jpg](http://soporte.cardinalsystems.com.ar/errorvmwareserver.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Network Connections on the host PC, you might try repairing the connections that are created by VMWare.  Something like "VMWare Network Adapter VMnet1"

I'm assuming that the network connections (to a LAN/Internet) are working on the host computer.  If not, I'd start by fixing the host first.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a vmware.log file or something similar in the directory that contains your vm. After you start the vm, are there any new errors in it?

Also, is the network adapter enabled?

Answer (score 0):

No Idea what I do, but now its working.

this is all I have done:

1. reinstall Vmware server several times ( more than 4 )
2. Fix network adapter
3. prey ( more than 1000 times)

UPDATE: One of the three VM does not work the other works perfect.